# PRIuPTR preprocessor bug in GCC?

Tags: c++, gcc, printf

The following program, when compiled as C++ with GCC 4.8.1

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    uintptr_t i = 0;
    i--;
    printf("%" PRIuPTR "\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

gives the following error message

```
a.cc: In function 'int main()':
a.cc:8:13: error: expected ')' before 'PRIuPTR'
  printf("%" PRIuPTR "\n", i);
             ^
```

It compiles and runs correctly with the Microsoft compiler, and even with GCC when compiled as C.

Am I missing something, or is this a bug in GCC? If the latter, is there a workaround?

Comment: Are you using `-std=c++11` to compile as C++11? This wasn't standard C++ before then (being part of the C99 library, while C++98 only included the C90 library).

Comment: Also, why are you trying to compile C code with a compiler for a different language?

Comment: @MikeSeymour Yes; it makes no difference either way.

Comment: @MikeSeymour The above is valid C++. It doesn't use any C++ features because it's a small test case, but the project in which I actually encountered this problem is a C++ program that merely happens to use printf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C standard says this about including the C header  from C++:

> C++ implementations should define these macros only when `__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS` is defined
>   before `<inttypes.h>` is included.

and it seems that GCC follows this recommendation, while Microsoft doesn't.

Rather than defining this macro and including the deprecated C header, a better solution is to use the C++ header `<cinttypes>`, which defines these macros unconditionally. (As noted in the comments, the C++ standard specifically says that the macro has no effect on the C++ header.)

Alternatively, stop using the C library when there's a more convenient (and typesafe) C++ alternative, `std::cout << i;`

Comment: 27.9.2 C Library Files [c.files]: `[ Note: The macros defined by <cinttypes> are provided unconditionally.
In particular, the symbol __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS, mentioned in footnote 182 of the C standard,
plays no role in C++. —end note ]` That's the only mention of the macro in C++11+.

Comment: `[c.files]` §4 Explicitly says the headers shall have the same content, aside from a few irrelevant changes.

Comment: @Deduplicator: And so they do; the difference is that these macros are conditional in the C header (when included from C++), and unconditional in the C++ header.

Comment: +1 not sure why I missed that detail when I made my earlier comment.